Is the following function $f(k)$ surjective?
Let $\omega(n)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of the positive integer $n$.
For a positive integer $k$ , let $s$ be the smallest positive integer such that $\omega(2024^s+k)\ne s$ , in other words $\omega(2024^j+k)=j$ for every positive integer $j<s$. Then , define $f(k):=s-1$
In other words , we search numbers $k$ such that we have $\omega(2024^j+k)=j$ for $j=1,2,\cdots,t$ , but not for $t+1$. In this case , we have $f(k)=t$.
The smallest positive integers $k$ with $f(k)=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ respective are listed in the following table :
1   3
2   63
3   15
4   879
5   49145
6   701765
7   812484789


Is $f(k)$ surjective ? In other words , can $f(k)$ be any given positive integer $t$ ?

Who can extend the above table ? What are the smallest integers $k$ giving $f(k)=8,9,10,\cdots$ ?
Remarks :

The function is based on the current year , but it is not from a contest.
The sequence is currently not in OEIS
The function for PARI/GP is f(k)={j=1;while(omega(2024^j+k)==j,j=j+1);j-1}


If $\omega(2024+k)\ne 1$ , we have $f(k)=0$.

I might include the first few values of $f$ in your Question between its definition and the summary of the scanning through its values searching for first occurrences.

To get $f(k)>7$ , we must have $k>10^{10}$

$k=17959411433$ gives $f(k)=8$ , but is it the minimum ?

@Hayatsu Is this a joke ?
